# Form Recognizer in Azure search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search, azure-form-recognizer

I want to index the contents in a pdf invoice to the azure search index in a structured form. Can we use form recognizer as a cognitive skill for azure search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Form Recognizer can be a custom skill for Azure Search. See here a How to guide - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-custom-skill-form